# Glob through a long list of files with curl and writing each to a unique, new file with a matching filename

Tags: bash, curl, ftp, glob

I am downloading several large sets of files from an ftp site using `curl` and writing them to new files with the same name. I want to use a command like this:

```
curl ftp/site/filename > filename
```

Here are some example files from the ftp site:

```
File:Compara.6_primates_EPO.chr10_1.emf.gz 30909 KB     8/3/10  12:00:00 AM
File:Compara.6_primates_EPO.chr10_2.emf.gz 13110 KB     8/3/10  12:00:00 AM
File:Compara.6_primates_EPO.chr10_3.emf.gz 24948 KB     8/3/10  12:00:00 AM
File:Compara.6_primates_EPO.chr10_4.emf.gz 45155 KB     8/3/10  12:00:00 AM
File:Compara.6_primates_EPO.chr10_5.emf.gz 17236 KB     8/3/10  12:00:00 AM
File:Compara.6_primates_EPO.chr11_1.emf.gz 37593 KB     8/3/10  12:00:00 AM
...
500 files later
....
File:Compara.6_primates_EPO.other_9.emf.gz 8980 KB  8/3/10  12:00:00 AM
```

There are a lot of these files, and I will be going through many long lists of them. There are *some* numerical patterns for which I could use

`for x in {1..N}; do curl ftp/site/file${x} > file${x}`

But there are also unpredictable patterns, like for example the secondary numeric index varies for different files. It is `{1..5}` here:

`Compara.6_primates_EPO.chr10_{1..5}`

and with the next file I might have something like

`Compara.6_primates_EPO.chr11_{1..7}`

and then there some oddballs like the last one:

`Compara.6_primates_EPO.other_{1..?}`

I know that I can't use simple globbing as in:

```
curl ftp/site/file* > file*
```

-- that just gives me `ambiguous redirect`.  I was wondering if anyone knew of a clever solution where I could glob the filename, save it as a string and then write the output to the filename, without getting *too* fancy... I know I could probably go and write a python script to do this more systematically, but it seems like there might be a quick `bash` solution that I am failing to think of...

Comment: Have you looked at the [man page for curl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)? The examples for [URL](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#URL) seem to indicate that you don't need anything beyond ranges in the ftp URLS.

Comment: @EtanReisner Hey Etan, thanks. My face is a bit red now, I should have looked into the curl docs sooner ;-) `curl -O ftp/*` works fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question was simple after all:

`curl -O ftp/path/to/site/*glob_pattern*`

The `-O` option will save the files with the same name they are given in the directory :-)